# Iterating and searching in LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am printing LinkedList like this:

```
    public class cinema{

    public static LinkedList <cinema> cinList = new LinkedList<cinema>();
    private int cinemaNum,numSeats;
    private String row;

    public cinema(int getCinemaNumber,String getRowName,int getNumSeats){
        this.cinemaNum = getCinemaNumber;
        this.row = getRowName;
        this.numSeats = getNumSeats;
        //todo
    }




    public static void addHalls(cinemaValues cin){
        cinema Cinema = new cinema(cin.getCinemaNumber(), cin.getRowName(),cin.getNumSeats());
        cinList.add(Cinema);
    }

    public static void print(){
        System.out.println(cinList);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "cinnum:"+cinemaNum+" row:"+row+" seats:"+numSeats;
    }

}    

public class session{

            public static LinkedList <session> sessList = new LinkedList<session>();
            private int CinemaSessionNum;
            private String time,movie;

            public session(int getCinemaSessionNum, String getTime,String getMovie){
                this.CinemaSessionNum = getCinemaSessionNum;
                this.time = getTime;
                this.movie = getMovie;
            }

            public static void addSession(CinemaSessions sess){
                session ses = new session(sess.getCinemaSessionNum(),sess.getTime(),sess.getMovie());
                sessList.add(ses);
            }
            public static void print(){
                System.out.println(sessList);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "cinnum:"+CinemaSessionNum+" time:"+time+" movie:"+movie;
            }
        }
```

the output:

[image]

I want a way to be able search all three parts of an elements using one of the keys

basically,
when the condition is Cinnum:2 I want it to return 
Cinnum:1 time:9:00 movie:toy
Cinnum:1 time:14:30 movie:Ratatouille

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: from where row and seats came. they are nowhere in code?

Comment: @swayamraina sorry that's again a similar LinkedList. I have now edited the expected output. thanks

Comment: still the same!

Comment: i have added the code for the first linkedlist too now if that helps. @swayamraina

Comment: I think it would be better if you use a hashmap of cinnum and list of details. `HashMap<Integer,List<Session>>`

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].